# Distinct from the table

Tags: nhibernate

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria<HCOSpendTable>();

foreach (ICriteriaItem<object> param in filters)
{
   crit.Add(Expression.Eq(param.PropertyName, param.FilterValue));
}

crit.SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.ProjectionList()));
```

Distinct not working.

```
crit.AddOrder(new Order(sortField, sortOrderAscending));
crit.SetFirstResult(pageNumber * pageSize);
crit.SetMaxResults(pageSize);

transaction.Commit();

return crit.List<IHCOSpendTable>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person)); criteria.SetProjection( Projections.Distinct(Projections.ProjectionList() .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("FirstName"), "FirstName")) .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("LastName"), "LastName"))));

criteria.SetResultTransformer( new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Person)));

IList people = criteria.List();

Answer (score 1):

You need to add property maps to the `ProjectionList()`

```
crit.SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.Property("id"), "id")
    .Add(Projections.Property("name"), "name")
));
```

Comment: when i did this i am getting exception 

Unable to perform find[SQL: SQL not available]

Comment: Yes its working after i made small change how to add the where condition for "sortField" != null or empty

Comment: crit.Add(Expression.IsNotNull(sortField));

but i am still getting the empty once

Comment: working after i add this

crit.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq(sortField, string.Empty)));